# Unity error: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct

Tags: unity, command-line, compiz, window-manager

After typing unity in the terminal to reset my top task bar, it loads correctly, but I get this stacktrace in the terminal:

```
WARN  2013-10-26 19:36:49 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Autopilot.Introspection' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2013-10-26 19:36:49 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Debug.Logging' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2013-10-26 19:36:49 xim.controller XIMController.cpp:90 IBus natively supported.
WARN  2013-10-26 19:36:49 unity.libindicator <unknown>:0 Desktop file '/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop' is using a deprecated format for its  actions that will be dropped soon.
WARN  2013-10-26 19:36:49 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2013-10-26 19:36:50 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2013-10-26 19:36:50 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:586 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct 
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
```

It still works fine, but I would like to know what this is about.

Thanks

Comment: I changed it to indents.

Answer (score 1):

```
compiz (decor) - Warn: No default decoration found, placement will not be correct
```

Lets analyze it like *Jack the Ripper*:

1. The message comes from `compiz`
2. The plugin is the decoration plugin (plugin because compiz uses plugins)
3. The message is a **Warn**ing, meaning: something is not *"ok"* but apparently we can still work like that
4. The reason comes last, for some or another reason, compiz doesn't find a default decoration, so the placement of the window decoration *might not* be accurate (the so called visual glich).

So, what tells you this? Almost nothing, is probably a configuration error that you should track down in compiz and repair, or could be a unity glich. Either way you should report it to their developers and get further guidance.